# Python 3.4 - How to create a template property for many classes

Tags: class, python-3.x, object, properties

In Python 3.x, is it possible to create a "template" property which can be reused by many classes ?

I have about 200 classes which correspond to products being sold in a shop. Each class uses properties specific to the product. The "get" and "let" function of each property perform sometimes elaborate sanity checks on the data when a property value is set.

Sometimes identical checks are performed on many different properties of many different classes. The only thing which changes is the property name. A simplified example is provided below for the "Robot" and "Box" classes. In these classes, a property checks if it is being set a value of less than 1 and corrects it.

```
class Robot():


   def setPrice(self,Price):              # <--                        
                                          # <--
      if (Price < 1): Price = 1           # <--
                                          # <-- Common check
      self.__Price = Price                # <-- to many
                                          # <-- classes
   def getPrice(self):                    # <--  
                                          # <-- 
      return self.__Price                 # <-- 
                                          # <--
   Price = property(getPrice, setPrice)   # <-- 


class Box():


   def setWeight(self,Weight):            # <--                        
                                          # <--
      if (Weight < 1): Weight = 1         # <--
                                          # <-- Common check
      self.__Weight = Weight              # <-- to many
                                          # <-- classes
   def getWeight(self):                   # <--  
                                          # <-- 
      return self.__Weight                # <-- 
                                          # <--
   Weight = property(getWeight, setWeight) # <--
```

Would it be possible to isolate this property into some kind of external function of class, which could then be called by many of my classes ? In other words, could something like this be implemented ?

```
class_or_function TemplateProperty():

   ... some code ...


class Robot():    

    Price = TemplateProperty()      
    NumberOfLegs = TemplateProperty()       

class Box():    

    Price = TemplateProperty() 
    Weight = TemplateProperty() 
    Height = TemplateProperty()
    Length = TemplateProperty()
```

Comment: Why not put the common properties in a base class?

Comment: @Blckknght: I updated my question. The properties which need a template have the same behavior, yet a different name in each class. Could that be managed with a base class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your object will never have more than one of the templated properties, then you can write a simple function that builds an appropriate property object and returns it:

```
def PositiveValuedProperty():
    def getter(obj):
        return obj.__value

    def setter(obj, new_value):
        if new_value < 1:
            new_value = 1
        obj.__value = new_value

    return property(getter, setter)
```

Then your classes would be:

```
class Robot:
    Price = PositiveValuedProperty()

class Box:
    Weight = PositiveValuedProperty()
```

This wont work however if any class uses multiples of these properties, since they're all writing to the same attribute name. If you want to allow more than one to be in a class, you'll probably want to specify an attribute name to the factory function:

```
def PositiveValuedProperty(name):
    name = "_" + name

    def getter(obj):
        return getattr(obj, name)

    def setter(obj, new_value):
        if new_value < 1:
            new_value = 1
        setattr(obj, name, new_value)

    return property(getter, setter)
```

Now you could set up a `RobotBox` with both a `Price` and a `Weight`:

```
def RobotBox():
    Price = PositiveValuedProperty("Price")
    Weight = PositiveValuedProperty("Weight")
```

The actual values will be stored in attributes `_Price` and `_Weight` if you want internal code to access them without going through the `property`'s checks.

Note that if your logic is much more complicate than the above, you might be better served building your own descriptor type, rather than creating closures and passing them to the `property` constructor as I've done above. A descriptor is simply a class with some of the `__get__`, `__set__` and/or `__delete__` methods defined according to the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html). Here's how you could implement the last version of `PositiveValuedProperty` as a descriptor class rather than a factory function:

```
class PositiveValuedProperty():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = "_" + name

    def __get__(self, obj, cls=None):
        return getattr(obj, self.name)

    def __set__(self, obj, new_value):
        if new_value < 1:
            new_value = 1
        setattr(obj, self.name, new_value)
```

As you can see, it's almost identical to the `property` code, since `property` is a descriptor that uses the functions you pass it to implement its `__get__` and `__set__` methods. You can however write more complicated descriptors. For instance, you could have your descriptor deduce its own name, if you wanted it to, by inspecting the attributes of `type(obj)` (or the `cls` parameter to `__get__`) and looking for one that is equal to `self`. That's a bit fragile though, since the descriptor could actually have multiple names (e.g. `class Foo: x=MyDescritptor(); y=x`) and and searching through the class's variables is probably slow.

Comment: What if I create 2 objects of class Robot ? Will Robot001.Price interfere with Robot002.Price ?

Comment: That should work in either version, since the decorators store the actual value on `obj`, which is the instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

### Simple solution for one descriptor per class

You can use a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html):

```
class MinValue:

    def __init__(self, limit=1):
        self.limit = limit

    def __get__(self, instance, cls):
        if not hasattr(instance, '_value'):
            return
        return instance._value

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if value < self.limit:
            value = self.limit
        instance._value = value
```

Use it in your classes:

```
class Robot:
    price = MinValue()

class Box:
    weight = MinValue(10)
```

Test it:

```
>>> r = Robot()
>>> r.price = 0.5
>>> r.price
1

>>> b = Box()
>>> b.weight = 8
>>> b.weight
10
```

### More sophisticates solution for multiple descriptors per class

Store the instances in the descriptor. To avoid memory leaks because you might keep references to deleted instance in a normal dictionary, use [WeakKeyDictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html?highlight=weakkeydictionary#weakref.WeakKeyDictionary):

```
from weakref import WeakKeyDictionary

class MinValue:
    def __init__(self, limit=1):
        self.limit = limit
        self._values = WeakKeyDictionary()

    def __get__(self, instance, cls):
        return self._values.get(instance)

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if value < self.limit:
            value = self.limit
        self._values[instance] = value

class Robot:
    price1 = MinValue()
    price2 = MinValue()

class Box:
    height = MinValue()
    width = MinValue()
    weight = MinValue()
```

Test it:

```
>>> robot = Robot()
... box = Box()
...
>>> robot.price1 = 10
... robot.price2 = .5
...
>>> robot.price1
10
>>> robot.price2
1
>>> b.height = 1
... b.width = 20
... b.weight = 0.4
...
>>> box.height = 1
... box.width = 20
... box.weight = 0.4
...
>>> box.height
1
>>> box.width
20
>>> box.weight
1
```

Comment: I run into a problem when a class contains more than 1 of these properties: weight = MinValue(1), height = MinValue(1), length = MinValue(1).    If I set a value to any of these properties, the other ones become equal to this value. Any way to modify the MinValue class above to work around this ?

Comment: Added a version that should do what you want.

Comment: Note that using a dictionary keyed by the instance requires that the instances be hashable. While that's the default for custom classes (which are hashed based on their identity), it may not be true for all instances of all classes.

Comment: @Blckknght The only way to break this I could come up with was to override `__hash__`, for example raising a `NotImplementedError` error. Do you have other ways in mind that could break my solution?

Comment: If you define `__eq__` in the class that is given the descriptors, it won't work. Custom objects are hashable if they either don't define `__eq__`, or if they do but also define their own `__hash__`.